# cut command in bash terminating on quotation marks

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

So I am trying to read in a file that has a bunch of lines with an email address and then a nickname in them. I am trying to extract this nickname, which is surrounded by parentheses, like below

```
email@somewhere.com (Tom)
```

so my thought was just to use cut to get at the word `Tom`, but this is foiled when I end up with something like the following

```
email2@somewhereElse.com ("Bob")
```

Because Bob has quotes around it, the cut command fails as follows

`cut: <file>: Illegal byte sequence`

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this? or a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
grep -o '(.*)' emailFile
```

should do it. "Go through all lines in the file. Look for a sequence that starts with open parens, then any characters until close parens. Echo the bit that matches the string to stdout."

This preserves the quotes around the nickname... as well as the brackets. If you don't want those, you can strip them:

```
grep -o '(.*)' emailFile | sed 's/[(")]//g'
```

("replace any of the characters between square brackets with nothing, everywhere")

Comment: This works, I just find it kind of annoying that cut can not handle this, but grep/egrep can.

Comment: I know `grep/sed`, I don't know `cut`. Possible that it can do the job - but I can't tell you how. Hope you can accept this answer...

Comment: Will do right now. I am now trying to tackle using uniq to count how many unique names exist, but that is freaking out about illegal characters too. I think I will just end up removing all of them somehow. looking into it currently

Comment: If you sort the output, you can then check "is this line the same as the previous line". Pretty sure awk will let you do that...

Comment: sorting also fails because of an `illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Ouch. What bytes (sequences) are giving you trouble?

Comment: quotation marks it seems. I am trying to remove them with sed, but that is not working. I am using sed like this to remove both single and double quotes `sed -e 's|["'\'']||g'`

Comment: `grep -o "(.*)" emailFile | sed 's/[(")]//g' | sed "s/'//g"` gets rid of both. Hard to make a valid expression with both single and double quotes in it...

Comment: I was just digging through the file a little more, and apparently it is not actually a normal quote character, it is some odd italicized looking quotation mark, so I guess I need to dig to try to finds it numerical value. I guess assuming simple UTF-8 was a bit naive. Do you know of a way to continue if bash hits an error like this

Comment: `grep -o "(.*)" emailFile | tr '\n' 'ZZZXXX' | tr -cd '[:alnum:]' | tr 'ZZZXXX' '\n'` does the job. The first `tr` "protects" the newline character with an unlikely sequence of characters; the next strips anything that is not alphanumeric (including quotes etc); the final one brings back the newlines.

Comment: tr failed due to illegal byte sequence. What the f***. I also tried sed to remove anything that is not alpha numeric `sed 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]*//g'` No luck

Comment: screw this, I am going to email the person providing me that data and ask what the heck is going on here

Comment: I slept on this... I suspect the file is encoded with something more complicated than single byte data.

Comment: I am pretty sure I found the issue. These are Chinese characters, unicode U+301D, I am not entirely sure how to get rid of them, but I will continue to look into it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23863/discussion-between-floris-and-mzimmerman6)

Answer (score 8):

Reset your `locale` to `C` (raw uninterpreted byte sequence) to avoid `Illegal byte sequence` errors.

```
locale charmap
LC_ALL=C cut ... | LC_ALL=C sort ...
```

Comment: This definitely worked for this. Is there a way to reset this for all commands once in a script, so I do not have to put LC_ALL=C every time. If not that is fine, but just wondering.

Comment: I did however notice that the `uniq` command does not really like using this, as it does not seem to work when using this flag

Comment: Side note, I got it to work kind of using iconv as follows `iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii < names > temp` This works, but for some reason, when I call `uniq` on this, it will return the same name multiple times. Just another obstacle of course

Comment: "return the same name multiple times"? I bet that when you look (using `od`), you will find there are differences...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$_=~/[^\(]*\(([^)]*)\)/g;print $1'
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/63Xgbc)